# Dagger 2.11 - Injecting different networkAPI implementations in acceptance tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, dagger-2

I have a simple app. It uses a network API (Volley). It uses Dagger 2.11 (using AndroidInjector) for dependency inversion. The NetworkAPI is injected in the MainActivity. For the acceptance tests I use my own TestRunner, extended from AndroidJUnitRunner.

To fake the real Network API, I use an ImmediateResponseNetwork object. This 'network' responses immediately. The instance is provided by a TestNetworkApiModule and declared in the module list of the TestAppComponent. See parts of the source code below.

At the times, before I used Dagger, I used the ImmediateResponseNetwork to define different responses of the networkRequest, dependend on the test. Which seem not be possible now, because the network is hidden in the activity under test. And after creation of the network I can't access it from the outside to prepare it.

I also can't test a slower network connection. That is why I would like to at least to inject another fake slow-response-network object and I would like to have the ability to prepare the response via ImmediateResponseNetwork.
How can I do this?

An example test I would like to write is: 
Testing, that the loading indicator is displayed, while an network request is running.

I have no idea how to implement this now. It looks like, that DI is in the way for easier testing, instead of the other way around.
I guess, there is something missing in my thinking.

The source code on which the question is based upon: https://github.com/Minsky/SO_Question_AndroidInjectionInTestsWithDagger

Sample Test, I want to do:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);

public void afterStartLoadingPleaseWaitInfoIsDisplayed() throws Exception {
        MainActivityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        onView(withId(R.id.activity_loading_indicator)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

My relevant test setup classes:

```
@Module
public class TestNetworkApiModule extends NetworkApiModule {
    @Provides
    static NetworkApi provideNetworkApi(Context context) {
        return new ImmediateResponseNetwork();
    }
}
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
        TestNetworkApiModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class
})
public interface TestAppComponent extends AppComponent {
    void inject(TestMyApplication app);
    @Override
    void inject(DaggerApplication instance);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        TestAppComponent.Builder application(Application application);
        TestAppComponent build();
    }
}
public class TestMyApplication extends DaggerApplication {
    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        TestAppComponent appComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

The activity where the networkAPI is injected:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView responseView;
    private boolean progressBarVisible;
    @Inject
    NetworkApi networkApi;
    ...

    }
```

Comment: It seems you have to use product flavours for something like this. Please see the sample repo with `mock` and `prod` flavours [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/)

Comment: @David Rawson. Yes, I know this approach and it works. I hoped, there is a solution without flavors. I don't like switching between flavors while implementing, running those tests is easily forgotten, But perhaps a flavor just for those acceptance tests would be ok.Thank you for your hint.

Comment: I tried many different approaches but they are all quite messy. Product flavours ended up being the cleanest solution. Alternatively you can use package private setters on your Application and Activity

Comment: I prepared the solution with the flavors approach as David Rawson 
recommended. It is in a branch of the original problem sample in the question, https://github.com/Minsky/SO_Question_AndroidInjectionInTestsWithDagger/tree/mockWithFlavor. There are three flavors two for mocking different kinds of networkAPIs.